# deluge: recurring corruption of torrent state forces me to re-check them every time

Tags: torrent, deluge

I'm using Deluge and get these errors for the same torrents all the time:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/_libtorrent.py:59: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<libtorrent::alert> already registered; second conversion method ignored.
import libtorrent as lt
[ERROR   ] 14:14:13 torrentmanager:1147 on_alert_fastresume_rejected:  fast resume rejected. (*omitted*/torrent/Fargo Season 3 Complete 720p HDTV x264 [i_c]/Fargo S03E06 The Lord of No Mercy.mkv): mismatching file size
[ERROR   ] 14:14:14 torrentmanager:1147 on_alert_fastresume_rejected:  fast resume rejected. stat(*omitted*/torrent/Keith.Jarrett-Collection.1967-2010.Flac-Tracks.Lossless/1973 - Solo Concerts  Bremen & Lausanne ( 2CD )/CD 1/Keith Jarrett - Solo Concerts Bremen Lausanne Disc 1.log): mismatching file timestamp
[ERROR   ] 14:14:14 torrentmanager:1147 on_alert_fastresume_rejected:  fast resume rejected. stat(*omitted*/torrent/B.B.King - Discography 1957-2008 Mp3 320 Kbps/2 Live albums/1965 Live At The Regal (1995) @320/09 You Done Lost Your Good Thing Now.mp3): mismatching file timestamp
[ERROR   ] 14:14:27 torrent:468 Restart deluge to clear this torrent error
[ERROR   ] 14:14:27 torrent:468 Restart deluge to clear this torrent error
Unhandled error in Deferred:
```

Then I have to right click those torrents and force a re-check. Next time I launch Deluge I get the same errors...

Additional info:

```
$ deluge --version
deluge: 1.3.15
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/_libtorrent.py:59: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr<libtorrent::alert> already registered; second conversion method ignored.
import libtorrent as lt
libtorrent: 1.1.1.0



$ uname -a
Linux lubuntu 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
No LSB modules are available.
```

Are there any workarounds? I've googled it but found no solution.